# Is Examiner wrong or is Proof not enough? (Modular Arithmetic)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[Exam question and proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMX1q.png)

My main line of thinking goes as follows: (Modular Arithmetic)

(mod 2 ≡ 0) , ( mod 13 ≡ 0)   =>   (mod 2*13 ≡ 0) which gives  ( 0 * 0 = 0 )   => (mod 26 ≡ 0)

=>   ( mod ( 2 * 13 )(2 * 13)  ≡ 0 )  which gives ( (0 * 0)(0 * 0) = 0 )   =>  (mod 26^2 ≡ 0)

However the examiner states that it is correct for (mod 26 ≡ 0) but not for (mod 26^2 ≡ 0).

I simply do not see how my proof is not enough. (Exam is in swedish so hope its still understandable.)

Comment: I can't see how this relates to the image or that it proves anything. $a\mod b$ is meaningful to me, but what does $\mod  b$ on its own mean?

Comment: You are trying to apply the fact  that if a number is divisible by $26$ then it is also divisible by $26^2$. You can probably see that this is not true. It looks like you correctly proved that the number is divisible by $26$, but that's all.

Comment: By the way is it common in Sweden to write $X|Y$ meaning that $Y$ divides $X$ ?

Comment: $3^{3n+3}=27^{n+1}=(1+26)^{n+1}=1+26(n+1)+26^2k\equiv26n+27\bmod26^2$

Comment: Your argument only implies that it is divisible by $26$, not by $26^2$. See the linked dupe for correct proofs.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not entirely clear.  As I understand it, you've shown that
$$
3^{3n+3}-26n-27\equiv0\pmod{2}\label{e1}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
3^{3n+3}-26n-27\equiv0\pmod{13}\label{e2}\tag{2}
$$
for $\ n\ge0\ $, and are claiming that it follows from this that *both*
$$
3^{3n+3}-26n-27\equiv0\pmod{26}\label{e3}\tag{3}
$$
*and*
$$
3^{3n+3}-26n-27\equiv0\pmod{26^2}\label{e4}\tag{4}\ .
$$
If so, then your examiner is correct, congruence (\ref{e4}) does *not* follow just from congruences (\ref{e1}) and (\ref{e2}) alone.  If $\ A=78\ $, for example, then $\ A\equiv0\pmod{2}\ $ and $\ A\equiv0\pmod{13}\ $, but $\ A\not\equiv0\pmod{26^2}\ $.  To obtain congruence (\ref{e4}) using this sort of argument you would need to show that
$$
3^{3n+3}-26n-27\equiv0\pmod{2^2}
$$
and
$$
3^{3n+3}-26n-27\equiv0\pmod{13^2}\ ,
$$
which is certainly doable, but neither of these conguences follow *automatically* from (\ref{e1}) or (\ref{e2}) just by themselves.